# Custom C# control loading slowly, using lots of memory

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I have a control that has a label, trackbar, and 2 text boxes. I have a form that can have anywhere from 0-25 of these per tab, and they load at runtime with data parsed from XML files that are either in the folder that contains the fully built program, or in the project folder. I can't figure out why the control loads so slowly and uses so much memory.

The controls are placed on the form, and the following code is called when the form is loaded, and when changing to each tab, since they're all lazily loaded by default.

```
    public msgInfoControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void init(string s, UInt16 insize, UInt32 init_val, UInt32 init_min, UInt32 init_max, double mult, double inos, msg inMsg, Point inGridLoc = new Point(), string anotherName="")
    {

        // set the min and max value for the trackbar
        set_min_max(init_min, init_max);

        // initialize the trackbar value
        trackbar.Value = (int)init_val;

        // make the text in teh text box update to reflect the initial value
        trackbar_Scroll(null, null);
        myMsg = inMsg;

        this.Tag = inMsg;

        name.Text = s;
        otherName = anotherName;
        int xGridLoc;
        int yGridLoc;
        if (inGridLoc.IsEmpty)
        {
            xGridLoc = ((this.Location.X + 85) / 184);
            yGridLoc = ((this.Location.Y) / 69);
        }
        else
        {
            xGridLoc = inGridLoc.X;
            yGridLoc = inGridLoc.Y;
        }

        myGridLoc = new Point(xGridLoc, yGridLoc);

        // initialize the SPN
        myMsgInfo.init(insize, init_val, init_min, init_max, mult, inos);
    }

    public void set_min_max(UInt32 inmin, UInt32 inmax)
    {
        trackbar.Minimum = (int)inmin;
        trackbar.Maximum = (int)inmax;

        trackbar.SmallChange = 1;
        trackbar.LargeChange = (int)((inmax - inmin) / 4);
    }
```

XML Reader method

```
public void start1939Control(RP1210Sim.msgInfoControl controlToInitialize, string spnName, ref msg inMsg, UInt16 sa = 0x00)
    {
        try
        {
            pgns = doc1939.Descendants("pgnid");
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
        bool newPgn = (inMsg == null);
        List<XElement> spnlist = new List<XElement>();
        foreach (XElement ex in pgns)
        {
            foreach (XElement spnex in ex.Descendants("spn"))
            {
                spnlist.Add(spnex);
            }
        }
        int count = spnlist.Count;
        int i = 0;
        string j = "";
        string l = "";
        while ((!spnName.ToLower().Equals(l.ToLower()) && !spnName.ToLower().Equals(j.ToLower())) && i < count) //While you don't have text user looking for
        {
            j = spnlist[i].Attribute("name").Value;
            l = spnlist[i].Attribute("shortname").Value;
            if (!spnName.ToLower().Equals(j.ToLower()) && !spnName.ToLower().Equals(l.ToLower()))
                i++;
        }
        if (spnName.ToLower().Equals(j.ToLower()) || spnName.ToLower().Equals(j.ToLower()))
        {
            String z = spnlist[i].Attribute("name").Value;
            String s = spnlist[i].Attribute("shortname").Value + "   " + spnlist[i].Parent.Attribute("idhex").Value;
            UInt16 insize = Convert.ToUInt16(spnlist[i].Element("size").Attribute("value").Value);
            UInt32 inval = Convert.ToUInt32(spnlist[i].Element("start").Attribute("value").Value);
            UInt32 inmin = Convert.ToUInt32(spnlist[i].Element("min").Attribute("value").Value);
            UInt32 inmax = Convert.ToUInt32(spnlist[i].Element("max").Attribute("value").Value);
            double inmult = Convert.ToDouble(spnlist[i].Element("mult").Attribute("resolution").Value) * Convert.ToDouble(spnlist[i].Element("mult").Attribute("conversion").Value);
            double inos = Convert.ToDouble(spnlist[i].Element("offset").Attribute("value").Value);
            if (inMsg == null)//If the message hasn't been initialized yet
            {
                inMsg = new msg1939Gui(Convert.ToUInt32(spnlist[i].Parent.Attribute("id").Value));
                inMsg.changeSa(sa);
            }//If it has, just add the new SPN
            controlToInitialize.init(s, insize, inval, inmin, inmax, inmult, inos, inMsg, anotherName: z);
            ((msg1939Gui)inMsg).addNewController(controlToInitialize);

            inMsg.addMsgInfo(controlToInitialize.myMsgInfo, Convert.ToInt16(spnlist[i].Element("location").Attribute("value").Value));
            if (spnlist[i].Parent.Attribute("refresh").Value.Equals("100") && newPgn)
            {
                timerServ.create100MsTimers1939(inMsg);
            }
            else if (spnlist[i].Parent.Attribute("refresh").Value.Equals("1000") && newPgn)
            {
                timerServ.create1000MsTimers1939(inMsg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (log != null)
                log.AppendText(spnName + " not found" + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Main method of main gui containing the controls

```
public RP1210SimulatorMainGUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        xmlRead.start1939Control(engine_speed_control_engine1, "Engine Speed (RPM)", ref pgn61444);
        xmlRead.start1939Control(vehicle_speed_control_engine1, "Vehicle Speed (mph)", ref pgn65265);
        xmlRead.start1939Control(fuel_level_control_engine1, "Fuel Level (%)", ref pgn65276);
        xmlRead.start1939Control(total_fuel_control_engine1, "Total Fuel Used (G)", ref pgn65257);
        xmlRead.start1939Control(odometer_control_engine1, "Odometer (m)", ref pgn65248);
        xmlRead.start1939Control(accel_pedal_control_engine1, "Accel Pedal Position (%)", ref pgn61443);
        xmlRead.start1939Control(brake_pedal_control_engine1, "Brake Pedal Position (%)", ref pgn61441);
        xmlRead.start1939Control(total_idle_fuel_consumed_control_engine1, "Total Idle Fuel Used (G)", ref pgn65244);
        xmlRead.start1939Control(total_idle_hours_control_engine1, "Total Idle Hours", ref pgn65244);
        xmlRead.start1939Control(total_vehicle_hours_control_engine1, "Total Vehicle Hours", ref pgn65255);
        xmlRead.start1939Control(total_engine_hours_control_engine1, "Total Engine Hours", ref pgn65253);
    }
```

Comment: Have you done any profiling? Are you sure code is being called when you think it is? I don't see anything there related to the xml file reading/parsing that you mentioned, but it's possible that your lazy-loading isn't as lazy as you'd like...

Comment: I've not done any profiling. I've only really just walked through with breakpoints. I should post my init method for the main form and the method that actually calls this one.

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you deserialize the XML into a proper strongly typed object model (using something like .Net's `XmlSerializer` instead of manually parsing all the stuff yourself) and use an `ItemsControl` to bind to that, as opposed to this horrible monstrosity.

Comment: +1 for appropriate choice of words (_horrible monstrosity_)

Comment: I guess I'll go do that then, but the control was slow before I was reading in from the XML file, and I'd really appreciate any help diagnosing the reason it's slow.

Comment: Regarding speed, have you tried running without debugging (ctrl f5)?  I've found the WPF debugger can really slow things down.  Otherwise, you've got to profile it, you'll find it more or less immediately why it's slow.

Comment: @Levykid: if it was slow before reading the Xml, then remove the Xml part entirely and work on profiling and improving what's left.

Comment: I can't find the option for profiling in VS 2010. After some searching, it looks like it's taken out. How can I profile in VS 2010?